# First order logic and identity

Tags: first-order-logic

Can anyone explain to me why $x=x$ is a truth of logic?

I know that a truth of logic is a theorem based on an empty set of premises.

For example:

$F\alpha \implies (\exists x)(Fx)$

From existential generalization.

Where $\alpha,\; x,\; F$ are an ambiguous name, variable and a predicate, respectively.

This is a theorem of logic.

How do you prove identity is a truth of logic in a logical system without identity?

Do we need extra axioms/rules of inference?

Thanks

Comment: See [First-order logic with equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms): it is an *axiom*. If there are no axioms for *equality* we cannot prove the basic properties: reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity, substitution.

Comment: But $F\alpha\implies (\exists x)(Fx)$ is not an axiom.

Comment: See e.g. the post [Rules of First Order Logic with Equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996876/help-with-rules-of-identity-of-first-order-logic-with-equality) as well as [Equality and its axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992776/equality-and-its-axioms) and [Open axioms of equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423315/open-axioms-of-equality) and [Some questions about the properties of equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787842/some-questions-about-the-properties-of-equality)

Comment: How shall an object (whatever it is) not be identical to ITSELF ? Does "$x=x$" really need a proof ? Barely to imagine ! It must be an axiom.

Comment: Mauro, i am referring to Suppes, page 104 and the rule of indiscernibles.

Comment: Compare with List of rules (page 99); rewritten in that form, the rule is: "from no premise derive $t=t$".

Comment: In the same way, the Substitution rule is: "from premises $S$ and $t_1=t_2$, derive $T$, where $T$ results from $S$ by replacing..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an axiom of [First-order logic with equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

See also  Patrick Suppes' *Introduction*, page 104: **Rule governing Identity**.

We need it, with Substitution, in order to prove the basic properties: reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity.

See also [The Logic of Identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity/#LogiIden): if we assume the so-called [Identity of Indiscernibles](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-indiscernible/#Form) principle as definition of identity:

> $∀F(Fx↔Fy)→x=y$

we may easy derive all the above properties.

From the principle we get: $(Fx↔Fx)→x=x$, form which, by tautology $P ↔ P$ and Modus Ponens, we get: $x=x$.

Comment: Thanks, great answer.